# Why is python list comprehension sometimes frowned upon?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Many developers I have met suggest it's best practice to go with simple loops and if conditions instead of one line list comprehension statements.

I have always found them very powerful as I can fit a lot of code in a single line and it saves a lot of variables from being created. Why is it still considered a bad practice?

(Is it slow?)

Comment: Related reading [5 Wrong Use Cases Of Python List Comprehensions](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-wrong-use-cases-of-python-list-comprehensions-e8455fb75692)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

List comprehensions are used for *creating* lists, for example:

```
squares = [item ** 2 for item in some_list]
```

For loops are better for *doing something* with the elements of a list (or other objects):

```
for item in some_list:
    print(item)
```

Using a comprehension for its side effects, or a for-loop for creating a list, is generally frowned upon.

---

Some of the other answers here advocate turning a comprehension into a loop once it becomes too long. I don't think that's good style: the `append` calls required for creating a list are still ugly. Instead, refactor into a function:

```
def polynomial(x):
    return x ** 4 + 7 * x ** 3 - 2 * x ** 2 + 3 * x - 4
result = [polynomial(x) for x in some_list]
```

Only if you're concerned about speed – and you've done your profiling! – you should keep the long, unreadable list comprehension.

Comment: Can you explain why loops are good for doing something with elements as in why is list comprehension not good there

Comment: They were designed for those respective tasks. List comprehensions have an expression that becomes an item of a list. For loops have a block of code. Expressions are good for computing values; blocks of code are good for doing arbitrary things to objects. Also, it's conventional to do it this way: readability is very much about doing things the way others expect them to be done.

Comment: One interesting thing to note: in the `polynomial` example, a big reason for using a function is *naming the concept*: the comprehension now reads as “evaluate the polynomial of all items” rather than “do something complicated-looking with all items”.

Answer (score 7):

It's not considered bad.

However, list comprehensions that either

1. Have side effects, or
2. Are more readable as a multi-line for loop

are generally frowned upon.

In other words, readability is important.

As an overly contrived example of the first bad example:

```
x = range(10)
[x.append(5) for _ in xrange(5)]
```

Basically, if you're not storing the result, and/or it modifies some other object, then a list comprehension is probably a bad idea.

As an example of the second, have a look at pretty much any code golf entry written in python. Once your list comprehension starts to become something that isn't readable at a glance, consider using a for loop.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of side effects?

Comment: Also, [x for x in mylist if x>5] what's so unreadable about this?

Comment: Side effects (in this context) are anything that modifies some other object. In the example above, `x` is modified inside the list comprehension.  It's not _always_ bad (e.g., `y = [x.pop(i) for i in [2, 5, 6]]` isn't necessarily too bad), but it often "muddles" code.  As Petr already said, don't use list comprehensions do something _to_ something else. Use them to do something _with_ something and return the result.

Comment: `y = [x for x in mylist if x>5]` isn't bad at all!  It's exactly what list comprehensions are intended for, and it's more readable than an explicit for loop.

Comment: @Optimus: That one is perfectly readable, and perfectly idiomatic in general. But some of the snippets suggested when someone asks "how do I do <5 nontrivial tasks mashed together> in a single list comprehension?" aren't. Things like deeply nested list comprehensions with 70-char expressions and multiple layers of calls to the more exotic `itertools` functions. As a rule of thumb I'd say it shouldn't get so long you have to split it over two lines.

Answer (score 5):

There is no performance hit (even if there were, I would not worry about it; if performance were so important, you've got the wrong language). Some frown upon list comprehensions because they're a bit too terse for some, that's a matter of personal preference. Generally, I find simple list comprehensions to be much more readable than their loop/condition equivalents, but when they start to get long (e.g. you start to go past 80 characters), they might be better replaced with a loop.

Comment: After gaining some experience using python, I do not necessarily agree with    your statement *"if performance were so important, you've got the wrong language"*. I mean practically every super optimized C library has python bindings now a days. And using python does reduce a lot of headache associated development time and effort. But, you probably meant that, If performance of a certain loop was very critical, it would be wiser to try out if writing the loop in C has any benefits, which I totally agree with.