# Replacing symbols using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to simplify replacing specific characters of a string *in-situ* - with a list comprehension.  Attempts so far simply return a list of strings - each list item with each character replaced from the check string.

Advice / solutions?

**Inputs:**

```
reveal = "password"
ltrTried = "sr"
```

**Required Output:**

```
return = "**ss**r*"
```

**Getting:**

```
('**ss****', '******r*')
```

Comment: can you add some input and expected output?

Comment: List comprehensions aren't meant for situations with side effects, but what you're looking for here is entirely a side effect (since you aren't generating a list you want to keep). What is wrong with your for loop, and why do you want to replace it with a comprehension?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068251/why-is-python-list-comprehension-sometimes-frowned-upon) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695488/proper-use-of-list-comprehensions-python) for more on list comprehension side effects.

Comment: As a side note, they're "list comprehensions", not "comprehension lists". It's not a special kind of list, it's a perfectly ordinary one, just built in a special way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this using a list comprehension, you'd want to replace it letter by letter like this:

```
reveal = "".join((letter if letter in ltrFound else "*") for letter in reveal)
```

Notice that

- We're iterating over your `reveal` string, not your `ltrFound` list (or string).
- Each item is replaced using the ternary operator `letter if letter in ltrFound else "*"`. This ensures that if the letter in `reveal` is not in `ltrFound`, it will get replaced with a *.
- We end by joining together all the letters.

Comment: That's what I was missing.... ELSE. Thanks for putting me out of my misery. Probably obvious I've only been using Python for a few weeks. Wanted to explore comprehension lists - but couldn't see how to get it to work this way around. Replacing the letters I had was easy - replacing the ones I didn't was driving me nuts!

Comment: this is a generator not a list comprehension

Comment: @alcyone_pleiades: The `if` here is different from the `if` in your original code. You were using an `if` clause in a comprehension, which filters the values, only iterating the ones for which the `if` is true. This answer is using an `if-else` expression, which always evaluates to a value, but one of two different values depending on whether the test is true. They may look similar, but don't mix them up.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Good point. A generator expression is a kind of comprehension, although a different kind than a list comprehension of course. In this case, it's clearer to use a generator expression because we don't actually need the list for anything, but it's probably worth explaining that in the answer rather than just changing it without comment.

Comment: @abarnet - no confusion here - I know they're different.  Just wasn't aware you could place ELSE here.

Comment: @alcyone_pleiades: If that's true, I'm pretty sure you _are_ confused. You _have_ to have an `else` in a conditional expression. So whatever you were thinking of that you didn't think could have an `else`, that's not it.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a different way to do this immutably, by using a translation map.

If you wanted to replace everything that was in `ltrFound`, that would be easy:

```
tr = str.maketrans(ltrFound, '*' * len(ltrFound))
print(reveal.translate(tr))
```

But you want to do the opposite, replace everything that's *not* in `ltrFound`. And you don't want to build a translation table of all of the 100K+ characters that aren't `s`. So, what can you do?

You can build a table of the 6 characters that aren't in `s` but are in `reveal`:

```
notFound = ''.join(set(reveal) - set(ltrFound)) # 'adoprw'
tr = str.maketrans(notFound, '*' * len(notFound))
print(reveal.translate(tr))
```

---

The above is using Python 3.x; for 2.x, `maketrans` is a function in the `string` module rather than a classmethod of the `str` class (and there are a few other differences, but they don't matter here). So:

```
import string
notFound = ''.join(set(reveal) - set(ltrFound)) # 'adoprw'
tr = string.maketrans(notFound, '*' * len(notFound))
print(reveal.translate(tr))
```

Comment: hah I typed up most of this same answer and then put the re solution instead ! +1

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I wasn't going to write this until I realized that it's the obvious way to optimize his `replace`-based solution by doing all the `replace`s at once, and not searching for the distinct characters by iterating the string… and then, once I finished, I realized I had no idea how to explain that, and almost deleted it, but people had already upvoted it by then, so I figured I might as well let it stay.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
re.sub("[^%s]"%guesses,"*",solution_string)
```

assuming guesses is a string

Comment: RegEx I can do... but I appreciate the suggestion nonetheless.