# I want print items in list one by one using list comprehension in python. How can do that?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing, list-comprehension

```
itemlist = [("Tatamotors",483.4568), ("M&M",953.8045),("TVSmotors",712),("AshokLeyland",142.2567)]


print([f"Item {stock} : Price = {price}" for stock,price in itemlist]  )


for stock,price in itemlist:
  print(f"Item {stock} : Price = {price}")
```

how can i print list comprehension object one by one like for loop does?

I tried unpacking each item in list but couldn't able to do it.

how can unpack each item and print in a line by line format instead of of returing list.

i removed list and pyhton returns generator object how can i print that?

```
print(f"Item {stock} : Price = {price}" for stock,price in itemlist  )
```

*Output*:**<generator object  at 0x7fd0af2bc5d0>**

*Desired Output*:

Item Tatamotors : Price = 483.4568

Item M&M : Price = 953.8045

Item TVSmotors : Price = 712

Item AshokLeyland : Price = 142.2567

Using LIST COMPREHENSION

Comment: `print(*(f"Item {stock} : Price = {price}" for stock,price in itemlist), sep='\n')`

Comment: In fact, there is no benefit in doing so.

Comment: Thanks Bro. Why there is no benefit?

Comment: In addition to reducing the number of lines of code, it does not bring any other benefits, and it will require you to generate all strings at once. If your list is large enough, it may crash your program. @vasu dev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084246/printing-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: No real use in list comprehension here, may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068251/why-is-python-list-comprehension-sometimes-frowned-upon

Answer (score 0):

```
itemlist = [("Tatamotors",483.4568), ("M&M",953.8045),("TVSmotors",712),("AshokLeyland",142.2567)]

print('\n'.join([f"Item {stock} : Price = {price}" for stock,price in itemlist]))
```

Output:

```
Item Tatamotors : Price = 483.4568
Item M&M : Price = 953.8045
Item TVSmotors : Price = 712
Item AshokLeyland : Price = 142.2567
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print using List Comprehension, but I think it'll occupy useless memory, In big scale environment it's not the best practice.
But ya there is the way below,

```
itemlist = [("Tatamotors",483.4568), ("M&M",953.8045),("TVSmotors",712),("AshokLeyland",142.2567)]
    
# Dummy list, which is no use other that printing
[print(f"Item {stock} : Price = {price}") for stock,price in itemlist]
```

**Output:**

```
Item Tatamotors : Price = 483.4568
Item M&M : Price = 953.8045
Item TVSmotors : Price = 712
Item AshokLeyland : Price = 142.2567
```